# Sorting several Tuples in a List

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

How would I sort a list of Tuples in Python. For example, I have:

```
aList = [ ( 'person', 20, 100 ), ( 'cat', 30, 900 ), ( 'dog', 5, 500 ) ]
```

So I want to sort the Tuples using their third values (100, 900, and 500) I would get:

```
aList = [ ( 'cat', 30, 900 ), ( 'dog', 5, 500 ), ( 'person', 20, 100 ) ]
```

When I use the answer from the duplicate question I get the same values back:

```
data = [ ( 'person', 20, 100 ), ( 'cat', 30, 900 ), ( 'dog', 5, 500 ) ]

def sorted_by_second():
    sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    return data

sorted_by_second()
```

and I get:

```
[('person', 20, 100), ('cat', 30, 900), ('dog', 5, 500)]
```

Comment: By default `sorted` will sort like that only. `sorted([ ( 'person', 20, 100 ), ( 'cat', 30, 900 ), ( 'dog', 5, 500 ) ])`

Comment: To your new problem: `sorted()` doesn't modify `data`. You need to either return the result of `sorted()`, or use `data.sort()` and return `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the python `sorted` [method](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting), which can specify a `key` parameter that is a function which takes an element in the list as an input and returns its value to be sorted by as the output (such as a `lambda`).

Example:

```
sorted_list = sorted(aList, key =  lambda x : x[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the 3rd item as key to sort:

```
aList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```